# Angular.js ng app is not recognized only for controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular.js and am having a issue with setting the controllers. In the browser, I am getting a error `'uncaught referenceError: myappApp is not defined'` for `myappApp.controller('HomeController'...)`. I am not sure why because the `ng-app='myappApp'` is set and works successfully and  it also is set in `angular.module('myappApp'...)`. Otherwise, everything loads ok.

```
one@localhost ~/angular.js-project/myapp/app $ cat scripts/app.js 
'use strict';

angular
  .module('myappApp', [
    'ngCookies', 'ngRoute'
  ]).config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeController'
      });

      $routeProvider.when('/first', {
      templateUrl: 'views/first.html',
      controller: 'FirstController'
      });



      $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home'});
  });


myappApp.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
    $location.hash(id);
    $anchorScroll();
    }
});

myappApp.controller('FirstController', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
    $location.hash(id);
    $anchorScroll();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Either do:

```
var myappApp = angular
  .module('myappApp', [
    'ngCookies', 'ngRoute'
  ])
```

or

```
angular.module('myappApp').controller(...)
```

When you do `myappApp.controller` that is looking for a `myappApp` variable, which isn't defined anywhere.  So either assign the result of angular.module to it or keep using angular.module as in above.